# The method openDatabase(String, null) is undefined for the type Context-----whats the problem

Tags: android

```
package com.reader;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class feedsDB{
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_FEEDS = "create table feeds (feed_id integer primary key autoincrement, title text not null, url text not null);";
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_ARTICLES = "create table articles (article_id primary key autoincrement, feed_id text not null, title text not null, url text not null);";


    private static final String FEEDS_TABLE = "feeds";
    private static final String ARTICLES_TABLE ="articles";
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "reader";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public feedsDB(Context feeder) {

        try{
            db=feeder.openDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, null);}
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        try {
                                db = feeder.createDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, DATABASE_VERSION, 0, null);
                                db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_FEEDS);
                                db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_ARTICLES);
                            }  
                        catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                                db = null;}

           }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

openDatabase isn't a method on Context. It is a static method on SQLiteDatabase. Looks like you could change your code to db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(...).

I would recommend reading the "Using Databases" section at this link: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db.  The recommended way to create a database is to extend SQLiteOpenHelper, overriding the constructor and onCreate methods.